# array for multiple where_in condition in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
$this->db->where('column_field1',$value1);
$this->db->where('column_field2',$value2);
```

For above two query we can write a single query as:

```
$arr = array('column_field1'=>'value1', 'columne_field2'=>'value2');

function select($arr){
    .. .. ..
    ... .. . ..
    $this->db->where($arr);
}
```

is there any solution for the where_in query:

```
function($value1, $value2){
   $this->db->where_in('column_field1',$value1);
   $this->db->where_in('column_field2',$value2);
}
```

as I have tried but didn't work:

```
arr = array('column_field1'=>$arr,'column_field2'=>arr2);

function select_in($arr)
 {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('table');
        $this->db->where_in($arr);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

I want to combine the where_in condition so that i can store multiple column_field and array for it.
    $this->db->where_in($arr);
where $arr contains pair of column_filed and array_of_value:
    $arr = $array('column_field'=>$arr_of_value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function select_in($arr)
 {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('table');
        $this->db->where($arr);  // change here
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

If you want multiple where In then you need to write it twice....It's not possible in single statement.

```
$this->db->where_in('field1',$cond1);
$this->db->where_in('field2' , $cond2);
```

Note: Where_in is similar to where id IN (1,2,3...)but in your case you are doing multiple where condition.

Comment: I want to combine multiple where_in() condition

Comment: even i cant pass an array in where_in() condition like:
     $this->db->where_in($arr);

Comment: edited please check

Comment: not possible? sure..?

Comment: yap according to it's [source code](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_query_builder.php#L872) it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Creating custom method is a reasonable solution for this, you can either extend database's active record class or write custom function which takes array and call where_in like below

```
function multiple_where_in($array){
    foreach($array as $key  => $data){
        $this->db->where_in($key, $data);
    }
  }
```

And call like below

```
function select_in($arr)
{
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('your_table');
        $this->multiple_where_in($arr);  // call local function created above
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query;
}

// create array like below, fieldname and field_values inside array
$arr = array(
              'column_field1'=>array('value1','value2'),  
              'columne_field2'=>array('value2','value3')
);

// call your select method
$this->select_in($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution for your problem.

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');
    if(!empty($cond1) && !empty($cond2)){
        $this->db->where("field1 IN (".$cond1.") AND field2 IN (".$cond2.") ",null,false);    
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
```

I hope this will helps you. Thanks!